# Connect remotely to file server on local network from virtualbox guest

Tags: networking, windows-10, virtualbox

I have Windows 10 LTSB running in VirtualBox on a Windows 10 LTSB host (Please don't ask why, it's irrelevant). But I need it to access the fileserver on the office network. To do this on the host machine, I connect through \FILSERVER\Users\username and navigate to find my files. How do I "see" this machine from the guest OS?

Answer (score 1):

If your environment and application allows it, you can connect your guest to your LAN in bridge mode (in Oracle VM manager: right click your VM -> settings -> network -> attached to -> bridged adapter).

Your guest system will then get an IP address from your LAN's DHCP server and is visible in your LAN just as any physically connected machine would be. In this case, traffic from your guest is still routed through your host, but your VM manager will do everything for you.

Answer (score 0):

Admittedly, this solution is incomplete as I don't know the tools to implement the second part of it, but it might set you off in the right direction.

This should work if your guest OS uses NAT to get internet access.

Add a route on your guest machine that tells it to send traffic for FILESERVER to your host:

```
route ADD <FILESERVER-IP> mask 255.255.255.255 <HOST-IP> METRIC 1
```

`<HOST-IP>` is the IP that the host is reachable at from the guest, not the host's IP in your LAN. Alternatively you can modify `<FILESERVER-IP>` and the net mask to create routes to larger parts of your LAN.

The second step is to instruct your host to actually forward the traffic, which the guest will be sending to the host, to FILESERVER. I could tell you how to do it with iptables on linux, but I don't know how to do it on Windows.